PnP modern search v4 filter web part not getting values from results web part
Using the latest v4 version (4.12.2) the filters web part doesn't get values from the search results web part as it should.
The column I want to use as a filter is a library choice column, mapped to an available refinableString managed property.
That property has been added to the results web part (and has values) and the filters wp has been connected to the results wp (and vice versa) so I'd expect the filters web part to be able to use it. All I see is "No available filter to display". Never had an issue with v3 so not sure what is going on.
